# Can't get an object from JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jhipster

So, I am currently using AWS lambda and I have a problem with weird behaviour.
If microservices returns a list of objects I can get all items by casting it to List.

JSON:

```
{
  "payload": [
      {
      "id": 35,
      "start": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": "OCTOBER",
        "dayOfMonth": 10,
        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "era": "CE",
        "dayOfYear": 284,
        "leapYear": true,
        "monthValue": 10,
        "chronology": {
          "id": "ISO",
          "calendarType": "iso8601"
        }
      },
      "end": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": "OCTOBER",
        "dayOfMonth": 10,
        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "era": "CE",
        "dayOfYear": 284,
        "leapYear": true,
        "monthValue": 10,
        "chronology": {
          "id": "ISO",
          "calendarType": "iso8601"
        }
      },
      "user": "admin"
    }
  ]  
}
```

and with simple code like this

```
return (List<Delegation>) response.getBody().getPayload();
```

I'm getting the whole list.
ResponseClass is pretty simple

```
public class ResponseClass <T> {

    private T payload;

    public ResponseClass() { }

    public void setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

but the weird thing happens when I'm receiving a single object in payload

so now
JSON:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "id": 35,
    "start": {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": "OCTOBER",
      "dayOfMonth": 10,
      "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 284,
      "leapYear": true,
      "monthValue": 10,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "end": {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": "OCTOBER",
      "dayOfMonth": 10,
      "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 284,
      "leapYear": true,
      "monthValue": 10,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "user": "admin"
  }
}
```

Same exact thing (beside that it is now out of list)
and when I'm trying to cast it the same way

```
(Delegation) response.getBody().getPayload();
```

I'm getting class cast exception saying I cannot cast `java.util.LinkedHashMap` to my type.

So then I tried to user Jackson mapper:

```
mapper.convertValue(response.getBody().getPayload(), Delegation.class);
```

but I'm receiving error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: Expected array or string.
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: xxx.Delegation["start"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:962)
at xxx.util.JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.java:61)
at xxx.util.JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.java:17)
```

`xxx` is just for privacy sake.
I'm using code that was generated by jhipster.

Delegation class

```
public class Delegation {

    private Long id;

    private String user;

    private LocalDate start;

    private LocalDate end;
}
```

setters and getters omitted.

The same error occurs when I just try to do
`mapper.convertValue(input.get("start"), LocalDate.class);`

where input is converted LocalDate (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: Expected array or string.
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1])

Comment: what is `T payload` which type is bound at runtime? How is an instance of `ResponseClass` created?

Comment: @Meiko Hey, I switched T payload to Object payload but that doesn't change anything. It is created by RestTemplate. ResponseEntity<ResponseClass> response = template.postForEntity("endpoint", request, ResponseClass.class);

Comment: Could you analyze the resulting `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (result from `response.getBody().getPayload()`)... has it the expected structure?

Comment: Yes, it has. I checked in debugger. When list is returned it is actually a List of LinkedHashMaps, which works ok when casted to List of myObject. But when only a LinkedHashMap is returned it cannot be casted to myObject. It is really hard to understand for me

Comment: If you want, you could add the class `Delegation` to you question...

Comment: @Meiko class added

Answer (score 0):

In the first JSON, `payload` is an array, which will be converted into a `List`. In the second JSON, `payload` is an object. It is not a wonder that you can not convert that into a `List`. You need to gather that object as a single `Object` and possibly adding it to a `List` if you prefer it to be inside a `List`.

Comment: ? I'm not trying to convert it into a list